# jdbc driver error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I wrote a class which working with MYSQL on Tomcat 7.0 server. I connected JDBC as external JAR. When i ran my class as Java Application all works good, i have my connection, and working queryes but when i run my dinamic web application on server(Tomcat) and script is going to my class function `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is come.

Here is my code:

```
public class db {

public static ResultSet GetUsers() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from `person`");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

    return result;
} 

public Connection OpenConnection() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
    return con;
}
}
```

This is function which use that class

```
private void Exist(String name, String password) throws Exception
{

    db data = new db();
    Connection con = data.OpenConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `name`= "+name+
            " AND password = " + password);
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Were you doing Microsoft coding before coming to Java?

Comment: on php, C# why do you ask this question?

Comment: Because of your naming conventions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jar file need to available for Runtime (tomcat). You need to copy mysql driver jar into tomcat lib folder.

Comment: Ideally the mysql driver jar should be under web application's lib directory .

Comment: Jay, I agree. One of these places.